# "An error occurred while processing your request." with facebook authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure, facebook-authentication

I have a fresh asp.net application which has facebook authentication button on it. When I do the authentication on localhost it works flawlessly but when I publish and try to do it on `work4me.azurewebsites.net` it comes up with the error:

`An error occurred while processing your request.`

I have set the appID, app secret, domain, correct URL, and `http://work4me.azurewebsites.net/signin-facebook`as the oauth redirect URI. But it seems like it is hanging for a bit saying "waiting for `domain name`" before giving me the error.

If I try to enable facebook authentication on the azure portal it works however after logging in the application crashes and gives me the error "Server Error in '/' Application.".

I have followed the guide to enable facebook authentication on azures website but with no luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

EDIT:
It seems to get past that point now, and the error is with the redirect URI. However I have followed [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication/) example and use the URL `https://work4me.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback` as the guide says but still it wont work, giving me the error that the URI is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few months since I first tried this, but I was able to get it working both locally and on Azure, by following the online instructions.

Did you enable User Secrets during development to access your credentials from Application Secrets? If so, you need to create environment variables in your Azure Web App to mirror these values under Application Settings.

Let me know if you still have any issues, then I can look into it some more.

All the best! :)

Comment: AFAIK i haven't enabled user secrets - I've pretty much only added the facebook authentication so far. I'm at a total loss for what to do as the error gives me nothing to go for.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll see if I can replicate this again when I get some free time. Maybe something has changed that requires some additional steps. You can also leave a comment below the official documentation to inform the author(s).

Comment: I seem to have moved a step forward (without having any idea how though!) but I am now able to get past and into the facebook authentication however it says my Oauth redirect URL is wrong

Comment: Ok, I just checked my FB developer settings for a couple of apps. For an ASP .NET web app, I noticed that the oauth redirect URI is just my application URL *without* anything appended to it. For a Unity game project, I noticed that the oauth redirect URI is the application URL, followed by /login/facebook and nothing more. I've already deleted my test web app on Azure and it longer exists at its URL, so I can't test it right now. But it seems like I just had those settings when I had it working.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I've tried to set the URL to `https://work4me.azurewebsites.net` but it still wont work, so I'm at a loss for why yours work and mine wont!